# Autolayout with localization without restarting the app

Tags: localization, autolayout, arabic

My app supports both Arabic and English version and Autolayout handles alignment of text and UI elements. But a feature I need to add is a language switch button that immediately changes the language. I even need autolayout to adjust as per the language but doesn't seems to take effect unless the app is restarted. Any suggestions how to achieve this functionality.